# How to read "Web Archive" file disguise as Excel file in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I have a bunch of files which have extension ".xls". However, it always takes a very long time to open up, so upon further look, I discovered it's actually **Web Archive** files when I opened these file via Windows' **Notepad** instead of **MS Excel**. It also began with

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related
```

The problem is that when I try to display the content of the file via the below code in Jupyter notebook, it returned two different error messages based on how I scripted to read the file.

If I use

```
myfile = pd.read_excel(file.xls)
myfile.head()
```

The error message is

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'MIME-Ver'
```

If I use

```
myfile = pd.read_html(file.xls)
myfile.head()
```

The error message is

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'
```

I think I know why I got the above two different errors message because if I look at the content in Notepad, the data is presented like HTML codes rather than a set of data displayed nicely in a table when I opened with MS Excel. My question is how I can "read" these data in Jupytor notebook with nicely formated data (just like when I open it in Excel) and do further data manipulation (e.g. delete columns, copy data etc)?

Comment: [This](https://tewarid.github.io/2019/06/04/extract-all-tabular-data-from-multipart-mime-documents.html) might be helpful.